# asp.net - Read username with providerKey which is String

Tags: asp.net, key

```
string temp = Membership.GetUser(o.username).UserName;
```

`o.username` is a string but the function expects a Guid, how can I convert it to a Guid, or something else which allows me to read the username through the string username ID. Simple cast `(Guid)o.username` doesn't work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152019.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `Guid.Parse(o.username)` or `new Guid(o.username)`?